# Pointing a Code First Entity Framework to a created database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating a Code First Entity Framework to create a database to where I point it to. I have an instance of SQL => `DESKTOP-98TG6JE\SQLEXPRESS` and another one => `DESKTOP-98TG6JE`

In my Asp MVC code, my connection string is like so in the `Web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreDB" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-98TG6JE;Initial Catalog=MusicStoreDB;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and in my `MusicStoreDB : DbContext`,

```
public MusicStoreDB() : base("MusicStoreDB")
{
}
```

But when I run the program, it creates a database in the `DESKTOP-98TG6JE\SQLEXPRESS` named `DefaultConnection` and on the instance where I want to create the database, no `MusicStoreDB` database is created. 
[Image of the created database on the wrong instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHYNA.png)

Can you please explain it to me why this is happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you connection string name provided in `ApplicationDbContext` :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MusicStoreDB")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot find the "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute"

Comment: It is under the Filters folder

Comment: All I have is the FilterConfig.cs. I do not see any Filter folder. I clicked on "show all files" already.

Comment: If you have MVC internet application then you should have this file. Then how the Simple Membership folders are being created?

Comment: I have "public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)" and "public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>" and in it the "public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }"

Comment: But the connectionstring name is MusicStoreDB in web.config so you should be having base("MusicStoreDB ")

Comment: So should I change "public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }" to "public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MusicStoreDB", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }"?

Comment: Yes you should.